How can I extend the pipe for my French drain?
My French drain doesn’t extend all the way to the back of my property. I have a very wet muddy corner in the back of my property I need to drain. I need to add an additional 50 ft to my existing drain. My existing drain is 4 inch corrugated rigid pipe. It runs about 300’ out to the sidewalk.
The existing pipe starts out really shallow. When I get to the existing pipe with the new section I will be underneath it. How can I connect the two pipes and maintain flow to the street without having to dig all the way again?

Please post a photo and/or diagram

Water does not flow uphill by itself.
So, you'll either need a pump (located where the end of the new pipe meets the higher end of the old pipe, probably in a sump-well for physical installation reasons) to bring the water up high enough to flow to the street, or you'll need to lower the pipe to the street until it can flow downhill all the way.
